# Moving array elements a certain amount?

Tags: java, arrays, encryption

I have a problem in which I have an array containing the letters in the alphabet. I was wondering what the best way to move the array elements a certain amount would be. For example, if the key is 2,

and

```
array = "A,B,C,D,E.."
```

how can I make is so that after the transformation,

```
array = "C,D,E,F,G..."
```

Would the simplest solution be an `if` statement?

Thanks

Comment: You say that you have an *array*, but your variable actually looks like a *string* containing comma-separated values?

Comment: So after the shift, is A and B at the end of the list or are they truncated?

Comment: @monkybonk05 According to the comment to my answer, OP wants them at the end of the list.

Comment: OP, the proper term for this is array rotation, if you need `A` & `B` to appear at the end of the list after the "shift". Look at my answer again.

Comment: What if instead of using arrays you used a linked list. Then, to shift, all you need to do is alter the head pointer. Not sure off the top of my head how to implement this in java so I won't offer this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
char[] input = ...
char[] result = new char[input.length];
int shift = 2;

for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    result[i] = input[(i + shift) % input.length];
}
```

As you can see, you need a `for` loop. An `if` won't do it. It will shift all `char`s two to the left.

The result will be: `['C', 'D', ..., 'Z', 'A', 'B']`

This method is called a [circular shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift).

Comment: if i did input.length - 2, that would give me an array which is 24 in size. What if I want it to be 26 in size, so Z maps to B? Sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: Forgot to ask what does the modulo input.length do?

Comment: @AkshaiShah This is used to restart at the beginning of the array, when you reach the end. Otherwise you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: I see, is there a proper name for that?

Comment: @AkshaiShah I don't think this "method" has it's own name. The whole process can be called "array shift" or "array rotation" (as mentioned in a comment to your question).

Comment: @Baz is it not shifting since that would involve padding. And I do not believe OP wants padding.

Comment: @jsn Well, then let's call it _cyclic array shift_ :D

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use an array, how about a collection, like List...

```
List<?> list = Arrays.asList('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
Collections.rotate(list, -2);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output

```
[C, D, E, A, B]
```

Alternative, use an array of primative class wrappers... e.g. Character, Integer etc. This will still allow use of Collections via the write-through Arrays.asList() method....

```
    final Character[] array = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
    Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), -2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output

```
[C, D, E, A, B]
```

Comment: sorry my friend, have to use an array

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] newArray = Arrays.copyRange(oldArray, shiftValue, oldArray.length);
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(char[], int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

EDIT: if you need to rotate the array, look at the method below:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29)

Or:

```
Character[] arr = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
List<Character> chars = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.rotate(chars, -2);
arr = chars.toArray(new Character[0]);
```

Comment: I think that will do the job, just wondering if from = 2, and to = 1, does that mean my new array will start at B and end in A?

Comment: It will throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. If you need to have from > to, it will be much easier to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Collections.rotate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29)?

```
final Character[] vals = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
final List<Character> list = Arrays.asList(vals);
Collections.rotate(list, -2);
/* vals will be rotated */
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vals));
```

... produces (see [ideone paste](http://ideone.com/tBN00)):

> [C, D, E, A, B]